# Convert RTMP Stream to RTSP for Mobile devices

Tags: android, mobile, mp4, rtsp, red5

> Convert RTMP Stream to RTSP for Mobile devices

I tried to google alot on the above topic but not able to get any finite answer. I have a red5 server hosted and now I want to stream mp4 files or my Webcam on Mobile devices. As red5 is RTMP server is there any way to convert the RTMP stream to RTSP ? or how do we can stream the RTMP Stream on mobile devices.

Comment: Cant you use Wowza Media Server?

Comment: Actually I would prefer to stick to Open Source Server :) btw how do we can achieve in Wowza Media Server?

Comment: wowza does it "automatically", you just need to point the url to the server using the rtsp protocol.. example: http://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html